# Does dereferencing a GArray unref it?

Tags: c, glib, reference-counting

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <glib.h>

void transform_pointer_contents(GArray* const arr) {
    GArray* const tmp = g_array_new(true, true, sizeof(uint8_t));
    const uint8_t example_num = 5;
    g_array_append_val(tmp, example_num);

    *arr = *tmp

    // Why does this cause a double-free error?
    g_array_unref(tmp);
}

int main() {
    GArray* const arr = g_array_new(true, true, sizeof(uint8_t));
    transform_pointer_contents(arr);
    printf("Arr length is %d/n", arr->len);

    g_array_unref(arr);
}
```

## Questions

- Why does the unref at the end of `transform_pointer_contents` cause a double-free?
- I suspect that the dereferencing of `tmp` also unrefs it somehow, if that is true, how does it work? I think that a similar reference-counted type in C++ would work by overwriting the dereference operator, but surely C doesn't work that way?
- Do I have a guarantee that `tmp` is properly freed without the unref?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Why does the unref at the end of transform_pointer_contents cause a double-free?

Presumably, it is not either of the `GArray` objects themselves that is doubly freed, but rather the dynamic space for the temporary object's data (`tmp->data`).  That would be because

```
*arr = *tmp
```

performs a shallow copy.  When you then decrement the reference count of the temporary, GLib deallocates that internal storage, which `arr->data` still points to.  When `arr` later becomes unreferenced, GLib tries to deallocate that data again.

Note that it follows also that the data storage originally allocated for the elements of `arr` was leaked.

The bottom line is that GLib does not support copying `GArray`s via structure assignment.  Instead, use GLib array functions to manipulate `GArray`s.

> - I suspect that the dereferencing of tmp also unrefs [arr] somehow, if that is true, how does it work?

unrefing `tmp` does not unref `arr`.  But given your unsupported manipulation of `arr`, unrefing `tmp` has a side effect of deallocting the element storage (then) associated with `arr`.

> I think that a similar reference-counted type in C++ would work by overwriting the dereference operator, but surely C doesn't work that way?

The dereference operator (`*`) has nothing directly to do with the observed misbehavior, and absolutely nothing to do with GLib's reference counting.  Do not conflate the distinct uses of "reference" in play here.  And C does not in any case have operator overloading.

The problem is that you have improperly caused the internal state of one `GArray` to be aliased to the internal state of another, so that when GLib frees one in response to its reference count dropping to zero, the internal state of the other is corrupted.  Not that the aliasing was ever a clean situation in the first place.

> - Do I have a guarantee that tmp is properly freed without the unref?

No, you can pretty safely assume that `tmp` is *not* properly freed if its reference count is not reduced to zero.  So do continue to `unref` it before you lose the pointer to it.  What you need to change is the structure assignment, as described above.  Use GLib functions to manipulate the `GArray`s.  There may be viable shortcuts for people who understand GLib well, but at this point, that's not you.